# Unable to build WebRTC code on RHEL 7.4 because of `GLIBC_2.18' not found error

Tags: webrtc, centos7, glibc, rhel7, gn

I am trying to build the WebRTC code on RHEL 7.4 server as per the instructions mentioned on below link:

https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/development/

But observing the below error.

$ gn gen out/Debug
../src/buildtools/linux64/gn: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by ../src/buildtools/linux64/gn)

Looks '/src/buildtools/linux64/gn' is expecting the `GLIBC_2.18' version , but RHEL 7/CentOS 7 can support till glibc 2.17.

I do not want to upgrade to RHEL 8/CentOS 8 version as of now.

I tried to build gn source code on RHEL 7, but getting different errors.

What is the solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 : Build example, gn .

`clang++` must support C++17 to build gn:

```
# yum install centos-release-scl-rh centos-release-scl
# yum install llvm-toolset-7
```

---

```
git clone https://gn.googlesource.com/gn
cd gn
python build/gen.py

scl enable llvm-toolset-7 bash
ninja -C out
```

... to get the executable `out/gn`

Comment: Thank you !  I am able proceed after using the executable from 'out/gn'.  But getting the below error now.                                                                                                                                    ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by ./src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6) .                                       Looks we have to use the 'llvm-build' executables from CentOS 7 server.